# Windows DNS server deletes its own A record on reload

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp, windows, windows-dns

Okay so I have never seen anything like this. Here's the story.

We have four DNS servers. Let's call them server01-04. server03 is set to be the primary one by DHCP.

Scavenging is disabled everywhere.

What happens is server03 is deleting its own A record from the DNS. If I create the DNS entry, it will stay there until I reload the forward lookup zone (or reloads itself after a few minutes).

Here's the audit log of the creation:

```
An operation was performed on an object.

Subject :
    Security ID:                SYSTEM
    Account Name:                SERVER03$
    Account Domain:                myfancydomain
    Logon ID:                0x323d924

Object:
    Object Server:                DS
    Object Type:                dnsNode
    Object Name:                DC=server03,DC=myfancydomain.se,CN=MicrosoftDNS,CN=System,DC=myfancydomain,DC=se
    Handle ID:                0x0

Operation:
    Operation Type:                Object Access
    Accesses:                WRITE_DAC
                            WRITE_OWNER

    Access Mask:                0xc0000
    Properties:                WRITE_DAC
WRITE_OWNER
    {e0fa1e8c-9b45-11d0-afdd-00c04fd930c9}


Additional Information:
    Parameter 1:                -
    Parameter 2:
```

And here's the one for the deletion. You can see that it's server03 deleting the record:

```
An operation was performed on an object.

Subject :
    Security ID:                SYSTEM
    Account Name:                SERVER03$
    Account Domain:                myfancydomain
    Logon ID:                0x323d924

Object:
    Object Server:                DS
    Object Type:                dnsNode
    Object Name:                DC=server03,DC=myfancydomain.se,CN=MicrosoftDNS,CN=System,DC=myfancydomain,DC=se
    Handle ID:                0x0

Operation:
    Operation Type:                Object Access
    Accesses:                Write Property

    Access Mask:                0x20
    Properties:                Write Property
            {771727b1-31b8-4cdf-ae62-4fe39fadf89e}
                    {e0fa1e69-9b45-11d0-afdd-00c04fd930c9}
                    {d5eb2eb7-be4e-463b-a214-634a44d7392e}
    {e0fa1e8c-9b45-11d0-afdd-00c04fd930c9}


Additional Information:
    Parameter 1:                -
    Parameter 2:
```

I have no idea why is this happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, go figure, a simple reboot solved the issue. I got the idea from [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=hu&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Femaildetektiv.hu%2F2013%2F02%2F17%2Faz-allandoan-kinyirt-rekord-esete%2F) very similar case (Hungarian article, Google-translated to English).